# How can I configure different endpoints for different stages using NLB and HTTP API type in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I'm working with AWS API Gateway, creating a new API, API Type = "HTTP API" (no REST API, no WebSocket API).

In this API, I want to have two stages: dev and prod.

Attending these stages, I already have 2 different Load Balancer, let's call them nlb-dev and nlb-prod.

Both stages, of course, have the same route. For simplicity, currently it is configured to "ANY /{proxy+}".

My problem:
a) If I configure the Integration for this single route with "Integration type: Private resource", it is very easy to configure to point it to one of the Load Balancers...but both stages end pointing to the same load balancer, so I cannot have different load balancer per stage.

b) If I configure the Integration for this single route with "Integration type: HTTP URI", I could use a Stage Variable to define the host attending the request....but so far, I could not find a way to configure this to the Load Balancer DNS or IP address (I could make a test pointing it directly to the IP address of the final server attending it, and it worked). I tried different forms of "http://nlbxxxx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", but I'm always getting RC=500.

I'm doing this to simplify my currently working API Gateway API REST configuration. And also trying to avoid moving to lambda functions....

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On NLB/ALB you can setup Listener Rules for each stage path.

As explained in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That may help, but it will mean having the same LB for both environments (DEV & PROD), which could not be safe to share.

Comment: If you need different LB then maybe it will be better to have two APIs, one per version. Or specify different routes instead of using "ANY /{proxy+}"